# Как из файла записать данные в структуру без разделителей C++?

Tags: c++

Есть файл с данными:фио, номер телефона и т.д. Между ними стоит разделитель, в данном случае запятая.

Вот данные в файле:

```
Иванов Иван Иванович, 9773672365, 12.10.2012, 12.10.2014, 0, 0
Петров Иван Васильевич, 9734672311, 22.01.2008, 01.11.2011, 210, 200
Васильев Илья Васильевич, 9714679805, 05.09.2010, 01.12.2012, 0, 2000
```

Вот код:

```
Client client[10];

while (!file2.eof()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        file2 >> client[i].firstname;
        file2 >> client[i].surname;
        file2 >> client[i].lastname;
        file2 >> client[i].phone_number;
        file2 >> client[i].start_date;
        file2 >> client[i].fin_date;
        file2 >> client[i].debt;
        file2 >> client[i].credit;
    }
}
```

В client[i].lastname записывается "Иванович," в phone_number "9773672365,".

Как из этого файла записать данные в структуру без запятых?

Comment: Можно изменить разделитель, который использует оператор >> на запятую используя std::ios_base::imbue, но лучше разобрать входную строку вручную с учетом запятых, например регулярным выражением.

Comment: по моему вы должны знать:    https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: На заметку - если отчество из двух слов состоит, то чтение сломается.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь распарить формат CSV. Он намного сложнее, чем «разрезать по пробелам и отбросить запятые». Не мучайтесь, найдите лучше готовый парсер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти всегда, когда входные данные "пользовательские", нужно писать "парсер", который будет учитывать разные "особенности". Также неплохо делать разнообразные проверки.

По поводу `while (!file2.eof())`  - уже многократно обсуждалось, что это очень плохой паттерн.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

// я эту структуру "восстановил"
struct Client {
    std::string firstname;
    std::string surname;
    std::string lastname;
    std::string  phone_number;
    std::string start_date;
    std::string fin_date;
    int debt;
    int credit;
};

int main() {
    // сохраним в специальном объекте, который умеет мимикрировать под файл
    std::istringstream file2(R"(Иванов Иван Иванович, 9773672365, 12.10.2012, 12.10.2014, 0, 0
Петров Иван Васильевич, 9734672311, 22.01.2008, 01.11.2011, 210, 200
Васильев Илья Васильевич, 9714679805, 05.09.2010, 01.12.2012, 0, 2000)");

    Client client[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::string s;
        // читаем с новой строки во временную переменную
        if (!std::getline(file2, s, ' ')) { break;} // а если не вышло, то просто выходим
        client[i].firstname = s; // в случае успеха записываем в нужную переменную
        // будем считать, что если удалось прочитать фамилию, то все ок.
        // но по хорошему нужно проверять все чтение.
        std::getline(file2, client[i].surname, ' ');
        std::getline(file2, client[i].lastname, ',');
        std::getline(file2, client[i].phone_number, ',');
        std::getline(file2, client[i].start_date, ',');
        std::getline(file2, client[i].fin_date, ',');
        file2 >> client[i].debt;
        file2.ignore(10, ','); // проигнорием запятую. 10 - просто кол-во символов, на которые стоит посмотреть вперед. Скорее всего и 1 хватит
        file2 >> client[i].credit;
        file2.ignore(10, '\n'); // проигнорируем перевод строки
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << client[i].firstname << "|" << client[i].lastname <<  "credit " << client[i].credit << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Код рабочий, но а если первым идет строка с запятой, т.е не Иванов Иван Иванович, а номер телефона и запятая (9882234944,) то client[i].firstname = s не будет работать.

Comment: ну логично, что если данные другие, то и код должен быть другой. Для с++ все равно, это номер телефона или имя. Если формат другой - нужно писать другую последовательность команд.